# Why haven't I been to the GM's office for at least 20 games?

Tags: nba2k14

I've been playing NBA 2K14's My Career mode. I got drafted into a team, and I always used to have a meeting with the GM about every 5 games. Later, I got traded to another team, but I still had a meeting with the GM every 5 games. But now, I am not having any more meetings with the GM in over 20 games, and I really want to trade. :(

How can I meet with the GM, or why am I unable to?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I think the question is why isnt he having meetings anymore?

Comment: You can manually choose to Meet with the GM. I think that options comes once you are a starter. The GM will also ask to meet with you at some point. For me, it was approximately 40 games into my rookie season. At that point, I was already leading the league in MVP, Rookie, Defensive player of the Year voting, 2nd in the league in scoring behind KD, 1st in steals, blocks, assists, 5th in rebounds (as a PG), had a 95% team/fan approval. I'm not sure what triggers the GM to finally ask to talk to you because I had been dominating for pretty much the entire season. He asked me 5 guys to trade for.

Comment: Also, different GM sitdown topics are unlocked as you get better and your career goes forward. I'm not sure when the demand a trade option becomes unlocked, but I had it pretty early.

Comment: @crush If this is correct, please write an answer, so this question can be closed?

Comment: @Halest It's what I experienced, but I feel like it's too unspecific to be the accepted answer. I was planning on experimenting with it some tonight and seeing if I can detect the real determining factors.

Comment: Na Crush, I tested it just now, you was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer by Crush, in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161703/why-havent-i-been-to-the-gms-office-for-at-least-20-games/161996?noredirect=1#comment216740_161703):

> You can manually choose to Meet with the GM. I think that options
>   comes once you are a starter. The GM will also ask to meet with you at
>   some point. For me, it was approximately 40 games into my rookie
>   season. At that point, I was already leading the league in MVP,
>   Rookie, Defensive player of the Year voting, 2nd in the league in
>   scoring behind KD, 1st in steals, blocks, assists, 5th in rebounds (as
>   a PG), had a 95% team/fan approval. I'm not sure what triggers the GM
>   to finally ask to talk to you because I had been dominating for pretty
>   much the entire season. He asked me 5 guys to trade for.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings. Can you edit in a link to where you found this information? We like to give proper credit. Thanks!

Comment: He wrote it in the comments mate :)

Comment: Adding a link to a comment is valid too :P I've taken care of that for ya.

Comment: cheers mate, really helpful.